# Vue computed function to match elements from 2 different arrays

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Currently, I'm working with Vue v2.x.x. I have an array:

```js
sectionTitles = ['Technology', 'Data', 'Poverty and Research', ...]
```

and I have `jobsData` that looks like this:

```js
[{'title': 'Software Engineer', mainTag: 'Data', ...}...]
```

I want to display `<li>` in an `<ul>` when the `sectionTitle` matches the `job.mainTag`.

I was reading in the Vue docs that you shouldn't [combine `v-if` with `v-for`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if-with-v-for), so I created a computed method to be able to filter the jobs. Here is what I did so far:

```js
window.onload = function () {
    var app = new Vue({
    delimiters: ['${', '}'],
    el: '#app',
    data: {
      jobs: jobsData,
      sectionTitles: ['Data','Poverty Research Unit', 'Technology']
    },
    computed: {
      matchingTitles: function (sectionTitle) {
        return this.jobs.filter(function (job, sectionTitle) {
          job.mainTag === sectionTitle;
        })
      }
    }
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="title in sectionTitles">
    <h4 class="h3">{{ title }}</h4>
    <ul class="list-none p-0 color-mid-background" id="jobs-list">
      <li class="py-1 px-2" v-for="job in matchingTitles(title)">
        <a :href="`${job.url}`">
          ${job.title}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
</div>
```

So basically I want to only display `<li>` when the `sectionTitle` (for example `Data`) matches the `job.mainTag`. How can I go about achieving this in Vue?

Comment: computed methods don't take parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@depperm's answer works well (+1), but I'll offer a more render-efficient alternative. [Computed properties are cached](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Caching-vs-Methods), so you could avoid the work of `matchingTitles()` on re-render. In addition, it might be easier to comprehend the template alone without having to jump to the implementation of `matchingTitles()`.

I recommend computing the entire list to be iterated, mapping `sectionTitles` to the appropriate iterator object:

```js
computed: {
  items() {
    return this.sectionTitles.map(title => ({
      title,
      jobs: this.jobs.filter(job => job.mainTag === title)
    }))
  }
}
```

Then, you'd update the references in your template to use this new computed prop:

```html
<template v-for="item in items">
  <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="job in item.jobs">
      <a :href="job.url">
        {{ job.title }}
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: {
      jobs: [{'title': 'Software Engineer', mainTag: 'Data'}],
      sectionTitles: ['Data','Poverty Research Unit', 'Technology']
    },
    computed: {
      items() {
        return this.sectionTitles.map(title => ({
          title,
          jobs: this.jobs.filter(job => job.mainTag === title)
        }))
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.11/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="item in items">
    <h4 class="h3">{{ item.title }}</h4>
    <ul class="list-none p-0 color-mid-background" id="jobs-list">
      <li class="py-1 px-2" v-for="job in item.jobs">
        <a :href="job.url">
          {{ job.title }}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your computed method to just a method. Then change your filter to return a value. Also for displaying in Vue you want to use `{{....}}` not `${...}`

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
    data: {
      jobs: [{'title': 'Software Engineer', mainTag: 'Data'}],
      sectionTitles: ['Data','Poverty Research Unit', 'Technology']
    },
    methods: {
      matchingTitles: function (sectionTitle) {
        return this.jobs.filter ((job)=>{
          return job.mainTag === sectionTitle;
        })
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template v-for="title in sectionTitles">
    <h4 class="h3">{{ title }}</h4>
    <ul class="list-none p-0 color-mid-background" id="jobs-list">
      <li class="py-1 px-2" v-for="job in matchingTitles(title)">
        <a :href="job.url">
          {{job.title}}
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed the delimeters becaused the Vue app is within an `.hbs` file ` delimiters: ['${', '}']`

Comment: delimiters weren't used in the original question so I omitted them from the answer for simplicity. `jobs` was different too...but this is just to show how it works